# Is the Katy Freeway the widest in the world?

Tags: road-vehicles

According to [this source](https://www.chron.com/neighborhood/katy/news/article/Bragging-rights-or-embarrassment-Katy-Freeway-at-6261429.php) and several others (like Sylvester Turner, the mayor of Houston), a section of I-10 in West Houston called the Katy Freeway is the widest highway on Earth. Its widest point is when it intersects Beltway 8 with a total of 26 lanes.

However, some other sources dispute that claim. According to [this article](https://www.politifact.com/texas/statements/2016/apr/13/sylvester-turner/worlds-widest-highway-not-where-sylvester-turner-t/), there are many highways with more lanes than the Katy. For instance, [there's a highway in Beijing with 50 lanes at a tolling point.](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation-now/2015/10/09/thousands-stuck-traffic-jam-beijing-china-highway/73644000/) I forgot where I read this, but another website says that Canada also has a freeway wider than I-10.

Is the Katy Freeway the widest highway in the world or not?

Comment: I don't know if you're gonna get a more definitive answer than what Politifact stated.

Comment: The question of whether that highway has 50 lanes [has already been asked and answered](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/30356/37236). It’s only 50 lanes wide at the one toll place which is only for a small amount of highway. You can see this on the map in the highest voted answer there

Comment: What does Katy stand for  ?  Give up ?  Missouri, Kansas and Texas RR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By my count, there are 27 lanes at US route 95 [here](https://www.google.com/maps/@38.785329,-77.1785216,167m/data=!3m1!1e3) at the infamous [Springfield, Virginia, Mixing Bowl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springfield_Interchange).  A few hundred feet further south, if Augusta Drive [where](https://www.google.com/maps/@38.7831109,-77.1795921,206m/data=!3m1!1e3) it acts as a frontage road is included, there are 28 lanes.

For [Katy Freeway at beltway 8](https://www.google.com/maps/@29.7844706,-95.5575427,138m/data=!3m1!1e3) there are 24 lanes, but where it intersects Gessner Road there are 26.

Comment: @MichaelK The satellite photos are a google maps reference.  No original research here, unless he was up on the satellite taking snapshots himself.

Comment: @MichaelK The [consensus itself](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/faq-what-constitutes-original-research) only says original research is mainly bad if it can't be verified without unreasonable effort, more or less. Dave's original research is quite straightforward to verify.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Ah, good point. I see what you mean. Comment withdrawn.

Comment: @MichaelK The original research rule only prohibits "nontrivial" calculations or analyses. I quote from Sklivvz's comment: 'the general idea is "high-school level or lower" is trivial'. I hope this clears things up.